# Apache 2.4 + mod_php/PHP-FPM + suexec + userdir on Debian 10

Tags: apache-httpd, php, suexec

I cannot find a working, modern configuration to resolve this. I'm using Debian 10 and installed Apache 2. I have dozens of users, so I enabled `userdir`. I do not want their code to run as `www-data`, so I enabled `suexec`, which works for Python or Perl (`AddHandler cgi-script .pl .py` is enough), but I cannot do this for PHP. Is there a way to handle this with standard `mod_php` from Apache, `suexec`-like with `userdir`?

If not, I read that PHP FPM is a CGI server, which can be used by Apache by `proxy` module, which can proxy PHP to this CGI, but in the `php-fpm.conf` I only can set a single user for this.

Is there a way to run PHP web script as a user that owns the script, like `suexec` is doing, together with `userdir`?

Comment: Take a look at mod_ruid2

Comment: I did take a look, but the last commit was about 8 years ago, so it is kinda EOL; do not know about compatibility too with the newer Apache/modules; and I think you have to explicitely set a single user, it will not change process ownership to the file's owner. https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-ruid/files/

Comment: `mod_ruid2` is on [github](https://github.com/mind04/mod-ruid2). Although 7 years old it still works and I know e.g. Ubuntu ships it.

Comment: Unfortunately Debian do not (I found bugs submitted, it was segfaulting). I think this shoud be doable without mod_ruid2, I do not have a lot of webservers knowledge, but this sound like a common problem, but info on the Internet is stale or does not cover userdir, PHP, etc. For example, I do not understand why suexec works for Perl and Python, but not for PHP?